# How to boot into terminal on Linux Mint XFCE?

Tags: boot, terminal, linux-mint, gui, xfce

I have a Linux Mint XFCE system running on a lenovo z70. I've been trying to boot into the terminal on startup (but still allow me to start the graphical interface with startx if need be). Changing these settings here did nothing: http://ask.xmodulo.com/boot-into-command-line-ubuntu-debian.html and the directions here: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/460 also do not work as there is no "quiet splash" line. I dont know if these are errors or what.

Comment: You didn't specified version on your LinuxMint. If it latest 18.x version, it use `systemd`, you need to use: `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` in place of `text`

Comment: Aha ty I did not know that. If you post that as an answer I’ll accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux Mint beginning with version 18 using different init system that calls `systemd`, so to be able to boot into console, one need to use:
`systemd.unit=multi-user.target`
Simply adding `text` to GRUB wouldn't work on such systems.

There a few methods you can use to boot into console by default:

## Method 1:

edit file `/etc/default/grub`

Comment line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` and add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"`

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"
```

then apply changes by running: `sudo update-grub`

Now, tell operation system what `systemd` target to use on boot:
To boot by default in terminal, run:
`sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Next reboot will go to console without loading desktop.

To revert changes above (re-enable boot to GUI desktop by default) you need to run:
`sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`

## Method 2:

Disable MDM service:

To disable login to GUI desktop, you need to disable MDM (Desktop Manager) service:
`sudo systemctl disable lightmdm`

To revert changes, run:
`sudo systemctl enable lightmdm`

If you want to start GUI Desktop on demand without changing previous preference, you can run: `sudo systemctl start lightmdm`

Comment: I just realized I never accepted your answer. My apologies!